# How do I change the app name for a .Net MAUI app?

Tags: maui

I'm using Blazor hybrid to build a .Net Maui App. The Solution and project name don't contain any spaces and I'd like to keep it that way, however I'd like there to be a space in the app name separating the two words. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this. I've heard in VS to right click the project, select General, and then change the Assembly Name, but this broke the app even though nowhere else was referencing that assembly from what I'm aware.

How would I change the app name for a .Net maui app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the name in the .csproj file. In the file you can find the method below. Then you can change the application name.

```
<!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>myapp</ApplicationTitle>
```

Answer (score 7):

Can you try this;

`Right click to your project > Properties > MAUI Shared > Application Title > Your title With spaces`.

Your project will still have the same name, but when people run your app they will see a name separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the answers and it wasn't changing.

Finally I found out that the name for android is in
`Platforms -> Android -> AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.application.name" android:versionCode="1">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="Your Application Name"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

change this xml node to your application name

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="Your Application Name"></application>
```

I believe something similar is for IOS